# wso2am-2.6.0 unable to generate token when GroupExtractor is enabled

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2AM-2.6.0 with group application sharing

When application group sharing is enabled

```
<APIStore>
<GroupingExtractor>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.DefaultGroupIDExtractorImpl</GroupingExtractor>
```

it is not possible to generate a token from the store with following exception

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-11-27 12:56:11,039] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID : 4t4aXBQTmW55av0KgGVuIseqGvAa, User ID null, Scope : [default] and Grant Type : client_credentials {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getApplicationByClientId(ApiMgtDAO.java:11516)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getApplicationByClientId(APIUtil.java:7426)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.APIMTokenIssuer.renewAccessTokenPerRequest(APIMTokenIssuer.java:157)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.accessTokenNotRenewedPerRequest(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.issue(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:129)
```

backtraced the code to

```
if (multiGroupAppSharingEnabled) {
  if (application.getGroupId().isEmpty()) {
     application.setGroupId(getGroupId(application.getId()));
  }
}
```

and the direct cause of the issue is that application.getGroupId() is null. As well in the database.

I already opened an issue 
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/issues/5874

but I hope there's is a way around using the application group sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the development branch.

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/5841/files

Edit: Seems that fix is not what we need here. New fix is added.

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/5875/files

Comment: No, it's not fixed, the pull is fixing methods getApplicarionById and getApplicationByUUID, but not getApplicationByClientId, I will add a fix

Comment: Yes. Noticed later and it's fixed now.

Comment: A related (extended question) , may I just build the wso2am-2.6.0 with the 6.x branch and it should work well?

Comment: carbon-apimgt 6.x and product-apim 2.x are the development branches.